# Laravel 5.2 MSSQL connection issue

Tags: sql-server, laravel, freetds

I'm using FreeTDS + UnixOdbc to connect to a remote MSSQL DB through a VPN. I'm also using Vagrant. I can SSH into my vagrant box and run my `tsql` command and connect to the instance I've set in my `freetds.conf` file.

But the Laravel app itself doesnt connect. It's being powered with Nginx. I get a `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] Read from the server failed` message in the `laravel.log`.

Here is my `freetds.conf` file:

```
[SDSQL2DEV]
host = xx.xxx.xx.xx
instance = sdsql2\dev
port = 65156
client charset = UTF-8
tds version = 4.2
```

Note that I have to set the tds version to 4.2 or else no matter what I do I cannot connect or run queries with `tsql`. Seems like I may have a deeper issue.

I'm sure the correct `freetds.conf` file is being used. I can run `tsql -C` and see settings I toggle take effect. Here is the output from that:

```
Version: freetds v0.91
freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
MS db-lib source compatibility: no
Sybase binary compatibility: yes
Thread safety: yes
iconv library: yes
TDS version: 4.2
iODBC: no
unixodbc: yes
SSPI "trusted" logins: no
Kerberos: yes
```

If I change the version to 7.2 which I would think is supported by freetds v 0.91 then I receive this message:

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 100 (severity 11):
unrecognized msgno
```

I'm pretty experienced with Laravel, just not integrating with MSSQL but I think I have the Laravel settings configured properly. Here they are:

```
// .env
MS_CONNECTION="sqlsrv"
MS_HOST="xx.xxx.x.x"
MS_PORT="65156"
MS_DATABASE="dbname"
MS_USERNAME="dbuser"
MS_PASSWORD="dbpass"

// config/database.php
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('MS_HOST', 'SDSQL2DEV'),
    'port' => env('MS_PORT', '65156'),
    'database' => env('MS_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('MS_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('MS_PASSWORD', ''),
    'collation' => 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

Comment: What's the SQL Server version?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64)

Comment: Have you tried setting freetds.conf's `tds version` to 7.0, to 7.1 or to 8.0?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. It wasn't an issue related to Laravel, FreeTDS or MSSQL, but rather an issue with my OpenVPN config and data compression. The OpenVPN client config file I was using had `comp-lzo off` set but in order to get this working I needed to update it to `comp-lzo yes`. I noticed this when I saw compression related notices in the log file and the OpenVPN docs led me to make the change.

Hope this helps someone in the future.